# как подключить мидддвар к отдельному роуту?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Миддлвар на чек авторизации

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("config");

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  //get token from header
  const token = req.header("x-auth-token");

  //check if not token
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ msg: "No token, authorization denied" });
  }

  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get("jwtSecret"));

    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({ msg: "Token is not valid" });
  }
};
```

роуты

```js
const express = require ( 'express' );
const { getLoggedInUser, authUserAndGetToken } = require ( '../controllers/users' );
const router = express.Router ();


router
  .route ( '/' )
  .get ( getLoggedInUser )
  .post ( authUserAndGetToken );



module.exports = router;
```

пример

```js
app.get('/example/d', [cb0, cb1], function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('the response will be sent by the next function ...');
  next();
}, function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello from D!');
});
```

Comment: в чем у вас сложности? как подключить - описано в документации

Comment: используйте `.all((req, res, next) => ...)`

Comment: @Yugofx  Степанов в доке такой пример app.get('/example/d', [cb0, cb1], function (req, res, next) {   cb0 и cb1 я так понимаю это миддлвар, но как применить относительно моего случая

Comment: так вы только что скинули рабочий код. `get` принимает и другие аргументы, помимо хендлера

Comment: @Yugofx как поместить [cb0, cb1] в мой код?

Comment: Если для всех запросов по данному пути, то `.route('/').all(cb0, cb1).get(...).post(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Разница вызова метода `get` на уровне `router` и `route` в том, что `router.get` сначала создает `route` и потом вызывает на нем метод `get`. Поэтому, отвечая на ваш вопрос, как передать промежуточные обработчики на конкретный метод, передавайте так, как передавали бы на `app.get('/', middlewares, handler)`, за исключением пути `/`.

По сути вызовы

```
router.route('/').get(middlewares, handler)
router.get('/', middlewares, handler)
```

идентичны. Под капотом вызов метода `get` создает `route` и передает первый аргумент в качестве пути (эквивалент первой записи). И потом забирает собственное имя вызванного метода и вызывает аналогичный метод на `route`, просто передавая `middlewares` и `handler` как есть.